# removing special characters

Tags: applescript

I need to turn this into a string using applescript:

```
\", \"resource_id\
```

The problem that I'm finding is that the "\" is used to tell applescript that the quote is intended as part of the string.

any thoughts on how to turn that entire group of characters into a applescript string?

Loren

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ASCII code in place of the backslash character and the quote character:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set bSlash to (ASCII character 92) ---> sets the variable bSlash to \
        set qMark to (ASCII character 34) ---> sets the variable qMark to "
        set theString to bSlash & qMark & ", " & bSlash & qMark & "resource_id" & bSlash ---> sets the variable theString to \", \"resource_id\
        display dialog theString
    end tell
```

Unless I misunderstood your need - but in any case, you see where I'm going with this.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is used as an escape character for special characters (the quote) in an AppleScript string, so to use the escape character in a string you would also have to escape it.  Your escaped string would therefore be:

```
set theString to "\\\", \\\"resource_id\\"
```